# Vaadin Multilanguage portlet component captions

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, vaadin

I'm developing portlets with Vaadin in a Liferay Portal , mostly with english component captions(names) like "Cancel" "back" "next" and so on. Now i have to make the portlets "Multilanguage ready" that means if an user has set the language of his Liferay page to english he should see my portlet captions in english , but if an user sets the language of his Liferay page to german, the portlet captions should be displayed in german.

Is there a way to check wich language the user has set as his main Language ?

an easy Example :

John is from  New York his main language is english so as soon as he logins to his account the language of the Portlet component captions should be displayed in english

Heinz is from Berlin his main language is german so as soon as he logins to his account the language of the Portlet component captions should be displayed in german.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting caption from your property files you can try with (assuming above class)

```
Button button = new Button() {
    @Override
    public void attach() {
        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(Translation_portletApplication.class.getName(), user.getLocale());
        setCaption(bundle.getString("first_name"));
    }
};
window.addComponent(button);
```

To see full context of answer refer to  [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148835)

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`user.getLocale()`](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/model/User.html#getLocale%28%29) of Liferay API.

To get the user object, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970986/accessing-the-user-from-a-liferay-portlet/975111#975111) out. More detailed information found [here](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/49639) (could be outdated though).