# How to fetch UserId of the User submitting the form

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.1.1.

I have created a portlet with `<aui:form>` having two text fields and a button.

On submit I want to know the userId who submitted the below form:

```
<aui:form action="<%=myUrl%>" method="post">
    <aui:input type="text" name="name"></aui:input>
    <aui:input type="text" name="addr"></aui:input>

    <aui:button type="submit" value="save"></aui:button>
</aui:form>
```

How can I get the userId?

Answer (score 1):

I hope the Users are login into your portal before you show them this form.

If yes than you can look at the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/970986/1734150) which show a JSR-286 specific way and a liferay specific way to get the `UserId`.

And if you are showing this form and letting guest users i.e. any anonymous person to submit this form, then obviously you can't get the `UserId`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PortalUtil. On the Controler side :

```
User user = PortalUtil.getUser(actionRequest)
```

in your jsp :

```
User user = PortalUtil.getUser(renderRequest);
```

Don't forget to handle exceptions, or user being not null.

Answer (score 0):

Type this in your java code:

```
String userId=ParamUtil.getString(portletRequest, param);
```

Answer (score 0):

On your java code use,

get **ThemeDisplay** from the request(*actionRequest*) and get userid from
**themeDisplay.getUserId()**